# How can I run securely test cases for user submitted code in node.js for an online IDE

Tags: node.js, docker, express, jestjs, ide

I'm developing an online code learning platform like Leetcode/Hackerrank with express.js where user can submit code and run test cases on that code.Currently  I have compiling user submitted code with "vm2" library within a docker container so that user can't run malicious code in server. This approach for running user's code in server working fine.
But for running test cases on user submitted code I'm facing some issues since I'm not finding any API in vm2 or Jest library where I can run jest inside vm2 environment. Currently I'm running test cases for user submitted code like below snippet with child process which works fine but I'm not satisfied user's code running outside a virtual environment which might cause security issue. Can anyone point me how can i execute test cases securely?

```
import { FileFata } from '@interfaces/util.interface';
import { createFileFromUserCode, removeTempFile } from '@utils/util';
const util = require('util');
const execFile = util.promisify(require('child_process').execFile);
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

class ExecutionTestService {
  static executeTestCode = async (executeData: string) => {
    try {
      const fileId = uuidv4();

      const fileName = `src/tests/user/${fileId}.test.ts`;

      const fileContent = executeData;
      const fileData: FileFata = { fileName, fileContent };
      await createFileFromUserCode(fileData);

      const { stdout, stderr } = await execFile('jest', [`user/${fileId}.test.ts`], { timeout: 10000 }); //here jest consider file directory from tests folder

      console.log('=========stdout===========================');
      console.log('stdout:::', stdout);
      console.error('stderr:', stderr);
      console.log('===========stdout=========================');
      await removeTempFile(`${fileName}`);

      const output = { stdout, stderr, error: null };

      return output;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error', error);

      return { stdout: null, stderr: null, error };
    }
  };
}

export default ExecutionTestService;
```